# Set-WinSystemLocale not updating the machines locale

Tags: powershell

I have a German VM (German Windows Server 2012 R2 image) which I want to set to a `de-DE` locale. I use the following PowerShell command which should set the locale to `de-DE`

`Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale de-DE`

But when I subsequently run `Get-WinSystemLocale` the response is `en-GB`.

How do I get the machine to update the locale to `de-DE` and get it to stick?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183960/how-to-change-language-region-and-speech-in-windows-10-with-powershell-script

Comment: Did you restart the machine after the change?

Comment: No, but I think the `logoff;exit` bit of the related question has kick-started it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the system setting and you have to restart the computer to apply changes.

Comment: Logoff/Logon didn't work but a restart fixed the value.